# Function Scoping in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, function, scope

Given this block of code:

```
def f(x):
    def g():
        x = "abc"
        print("x =", x)
    def h():
        z = x
        print("z =", z)
    x += 1
    print("x =", x)
    h()
    g()
    print("x =", x)
    return g

x = 3
z = f(x)
print("x =", x)
print("z =", z)
z()
```

Question: How is it possible that the last line returns a value of "x = abc" when I have not defined a function called z?

edit in the code: I accidentally set the parameter of g to be x when it should've been empty.

Comment: I'm not getting the same output. In fact, I'm getting an error: `TypeError: g() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`. Also, you did indeed assign a function to `z`: `z = f(x)` and `f` returns the function `g`.

Comment: Of course you defined a function `z`; the return value of `f(x)` is the function `g` that you define inside `f`.

Comment: Your code literally prints out the value of `z` before you call it... I don't understand how you can still say you haven't defined `z`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is it possible that the last line returns a value of "x = abc" when I have not defined a function called z?

To see how your code is being executed - and why the last line of output is `x = abc`, I've added some prints statements to your code:

```
def f(x):
    print('-----------control is in "f"-----------')
    def g():
        print('-----------control is in "g-----------')
        x = "abc"
        print("x =", x)
    def h():
        print('-----------control is in "h"-----------')
        z = x
        print("z =", z)
    x += 1
    print("x =", x)
    h()
    g()
    print("x =", x)
    return g

x = 3
z = f(x)
print("x =", x)
print("z =", z)
z()
```

The above modified program outputs:

```
-----------control is in "f"-----------
x = 4
-----------control is in "h"-----------
z = 4
-----------control is out of "h"-----------
-----------control is in "g"-----------
x = abc
-----------control is out of "g"-----------
x = 4
-----------control is out of "f"-----------
x = 3
z = <function f.<locals>.g at 0x7f2aee25b6a8>
-----------control is in "g"-----------
x = abc
-----------control is out of "g"-----------
```

As you can see, in the last part of the code the function `g` is called, which is how the line `x = abc` is printed. *How?* Because of this line:

```
z = f(x)
```

The `f` function returns a ***function object***; `g`. A reference to the `g` function is then bound to the variable `z`. You can see this yourself in the output above:

```
z = <function f.<locals>.g at 0x7f2aee25b6a8>
```

And at the very end of your code, you call the function - `g` - bound to `z`:

```
z()
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have to do with scope. If your last line was

```
 g()
```

it wouldn't work, as you expect. But, with the line

```
 z = f(x)
```

you bind the name `z` to the return of `f(x)` which is the body of function `g(x)`. At the point you call `z()`, the function `g` is not visible, but `z` is bound to it.

Additional note: if `g(x)` didn't redefine the value of `x`, it would keep the value of `x` passed to `f(x)`. That *would* have to do with scope, and it would be a *closure*

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explicitly defined a function named "z", but `z` is bound to a function because that's what `f(x)` returns.

Cutting down your (unnecessarily large) example a bit:

```
>>> def f():
...     def g():
...         print("hello")
...     return g
... 
>>> f()
<function g at 0x00000000024AC978>
```

where we see that `f()` returns the (locally defined) function `g`.

```
>>> z = f()
>>> z
<function g at 0x00000000024AC9E8>
```

and `z` is bound to the function that `f()` returned, `g`.

(You may have noticed that this `g` has a different address from the previous `g`. That's because each invocation `f()` creates a new function that it returns.)

```
>>> z()
hello
```

this calls the function that `f` returned, and so does this:

```
>>> f()()
hello
```